# Make an IF-like statement with Enum

Tags: java, if-statement, enums

How would I go about making an If-like statment based on a Enum value.

My Enum gameStatus has the states WON, LOST, CONTINUE, and NOTSTARTED. I want to make a decision based on the current Enum value.

Something that would work like this:

```
if(gameStatus == WON)
{
    point++;
}
else if(gameStatus == LOST)
{
    point--;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few reasonable options. You can either [`static import`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html#staticimport) the enum fields:

```
import static com.example.foo.GameStatus.*;
```

or instead *qualify* them with the enum type name, so that your code actually looks like

```
if(gameStatus == GameStatus.WON)
{
    point++;
}
else if(gameStatus == GameStatus.LOST)
{
    point--;
}
```

or you can avoid both if you use a [`switch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) instead of `if/else`:

```
switch (gameStatus) {
    case WON:
        point++;
        break;
    case LOST:
        point--;
        break;   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a third option in your scenario, which is to define an abstract method on the enum class, and override the method so there is no if else or switch at all!

```
   ...
   point = point + gameStatus.score();
   ...

    enum STATE {
      WIN {
            @Override
            public int score() {
                return 1;
            }
        }, 
      LOSE {
            @Override
            public int score() {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        public abstract int score();
    }
```

Comment: Yup, this is a nice solution as well. That said, using an abstract method which each field implements individually is a bit excessive. A simple `return this.score` where `score` is a field passed to the constructor would be less verbose and cleaner.